# How do you prevent blank lines when checking answers in an array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, do-while, getchar

I am making a Bingo game in C for a project and have made it through the initial board creation:
`B = 1-20, I = 21-40, N = 41-60, G = 61-80, O = 81-99`.
I have also been able to randomly generate a letter/number pair that doesn't repeat that is to be used to play the game per the following:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    int rollcount = 0, rollc, rollr, nohund, basec=5, base=20;
    const char BINGO[5] = {'B','I','N','G','O'};
    bool check[101];

    //fills check array with falses that will change to true as numbers are picked.        
    for(int i = 0; I < 100; i++) 
        check[i]=false;
    
    //marks free space as true, free = 100 on board
    check[100]=true; 

    do
    {
        //test var to prevent duplicate "rolls" until a game is won
        bool reroll=true; 

        rollcount++;

        //here's where the problem starts
        //This is meant to loop if the number rolled has been rolled before.
        do  
        {
            //getchar();
            if(getchar() == 'q')
            {
               //future code to display stats and escape game
               return 0;
            }

            rollc = rand() %basec;  //pick random column

            //pick random number in range of selected column
            rollr = rand() %base + 1;
            rollr += (rollc * 20);  

            //limits last col to 99 instead of 100
            nohund = (rollr == 100 ? rollr -= 1 : rollr);  

            if (check[rollr] == false)  //checks if number has been used
            {
                //prints the number of the roll, column letter, and random number
                printf("%d: %c-%d", rollcount, BINGO[rollc], rollr);
                    
                check[rollr]=true;  //prevents future use of that number
                reroll=false;  //escapes loop to roll another number
            }
        }
        //roll current roll again when duplicate is generated
        while(reroll==true);  
    }
    //intended to roll with each press of 'ENTER'
    while(getchar()=='\n');  
}
```

I have tried a few things.  As written above, the major problem is if a duplicate is found, it shows the blank line from the `getchar()` input in the `if()` statement.  As more numbers are found, wider and wider gaps between lines appear (due to needing more `ENTER` presses to find a unique number), leaving a mostly blank screen.  With a single `ENTER` press, I need it to loop until it finds a good number.  If I get rid of all `getchar()` expressions, the program will do this, and I can press `ENTER` until I get `99` unique numbers, but I need to allow to press `q` to quit the program.

Example Output

```
1: B-15  
2: G-78  
3: I-37  
4: G-62
```

To summarize, I need it to display numbers like it does without `getchar()`, make it through all `99` possibilities, and let me quit with `q`.

Please help, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Put the numbers 1 thru 99 in an array, and [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle) the array. The shuffled array has all the numbers in random order with no duplicates. To figure out the column for a number, use `col = (n-1) / 15`

Comment: `for(int i = 0; I < 100; i++)` uppercase `i` is "sqrt(-1)" (if you included `<complex.h>`

Comment: @user3386109 I was not previously aware of the Fisher-Yates shuffle, thanks.  I will explore that.  But my immediate need is outputting the list of numbers one at a time and can escape with `q` at any point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first apply some fixes to other parts of the code, to make sure it all works as intended. This is the typical signature for a main function without parameters:

```
int main(void)
```

The middle `I` here needs to be lowercase, otherwise the code won't compile or it will use the imaginary number from the complex numbers:

```
// Note: index 0 is not used
for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
```

The most direct way of making the program work, would be to move the `getchar() == 'q'` check to *before* the do-loop. The function of the do-loop is now to loop until it finds a number which hasn't been chosen before. The problem is now that this will loop forever if all numbers are taken. Therefore, we'll add an additional check: only loop if there are still numbers available.

```
if(getchar() == 'q')
{
    return 0;
}

bool aNumberIsAvailable;
do
{
    // ... same code as before ...

    aNumberIsAvailable = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
    {
        if (!check[i])
        {
            aNumberIsAvailable = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
while(reroll==true && aNumberIsAvailable);
```

That said, there are better ways to design this program. One simple step is to combine the two `getchar`s into one, as if it is a menu: A `'\n'` result means "roll another number" and a `'q'` result means "quit". As user3386109 suggested, there are better ways to solve the "sample without replacement"-problem.
Finally, note that `getchar` does *not* detect key presses. It simply reads a single character from the (terminal) input buffer. If you would like see actual key up/down movements, you will need a library which gives you more direct access to the keyboard such as SDL2.

Comment: Thank you, the biggest factor was moving the `getchar` to above the loop.  And thank you for the help with the forever loop when all numbers were taken.  I hadn't mentioned this problem, but it was bugging me (though was ultimately self-solving when I added the code to stop the game once a BINGO occurred, meaning you never get to the last number).  And I do think I need the `+1`  for `rollr` to prevent rolling a `0` do I not?

Comment: @MatthewSechrist Thanks for getting back to this! I didn't realize that index 0 wasn't used (it _is_ explicitly set to `false` in the initialization and I'm not too familiar with Bingo :-) ). I've updated the answer.